# How to make changes to a flutter plugin that has been added locally?

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

I created a plugin for my project and put it at the same level as my flutter project directory

```
-- plugin-name  
-- your flutter directory -- lib
                          -- android
                          -- ios etc etc
```

Then I reference it in my pubspec.yaml file like so.

```
dependencies:
 plugin-name:
   path: ../plugin-name
```

If I try to make a new method in the plugin to reference in my main project it will say it does not exist. I tried running a flutter clean and flutter pub get in both the plugin and the main project but that does not work. The only thing that seems to work is if I delete the plugin from my main project, make the changes to the plugin then re-add it. There must be a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

After a flutter clean and changing my reference in pubspec.yaml to

```
dependencies:
 plugin-name:
   path: ./plugin-name
```

It seems to be recognizing my updates on the fly.